# Private variable cannot reference to another method in the same class

Tags: java, variables, reference

Im new to Java and today i have a problem with my code when I trying to do ActionListener
My java class look like here:

```
public class exam{
    private void createForm(){
        ...
        JButton jbtn = new JButton("OK");
        jbtn.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
        ...
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        exam ex = new exam();
        ex.createForm();
    }
    public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        //IDE show that no variable name "jbtn"
        if (ae.getSource() == jbtn){
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "i have a problem with my code". What problem?

Comment: You don't have any "private variables" here - you have *local* variables.

Comment: OK @JonSkeet , it's local variable

Comment: @LutzHorn Sorry about bad English skill

Comment: @user3630076 It's not a problem with your English: the question should be more specific. Someone reading this question should be able to see what the problem is straight away. For example, you could use your code comment in the description: "When I try to access the jbtn variable, my IDE shows that it doesn't exist."

Comment: Sounds like you could do with reading https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Comment: @karaken12 OK i got it bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `jbtn` variable is *declared* within the `createForm` method. Java uses what are called "scoping rules" to make sure you don't accidentally use variables you don't mean to. By declaring `jbtn` in `createForm`, you are telling the Java compiler that you only want to use it in that method, and nowhere else. This is called a "local" variable (as in, it is local to the method).

You probably want to use a "member variable" (it is a *member* of the class). This is declared inside the class, but outside of any method. In your case, this looks like this:

```
public class exam{
    JButton jbtn;

    private void createForm(){
        ...
        jbtn = new JButton("OK");
        jbtn.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
        ...
    }
```

The declaration of the variable is now at the class level, and in `createForm` it is being referenced in the same way as in `ActionPerformed`.

This is a fairly basic concept in Java, so you might want to take a look at some Java tutorials that go over this ground. The [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) is a good place to start.